# Is there any way to enter an instance by yourself?

Tags: defiance

I'd like to visit the Explosions 101 map and drive around a Cerberus jeep for a while, but I can't find any way to enter an instance by yourself.  Does anyone know of a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to solo Co-operative or start your own custom party for competitive Maps you need party.